# How do I type piecewise functions in pages?

Tags: pages

Is it possible to use equation editor to write piecewise functions?

e.g.

[image]

Comment: You already got (and accepted) an answer, but it might be helpful for future visitors to understand what you mean by "piecewise"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter the equations in pages using LaTeX and MathML with `Insert` -> `Equation...` or pressing <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd>+<kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

It'll look like this:

```
|x| = \begin{cases}
 -x, & \mbox{if } x < 0 \\
 x,  & \mbox{if } x \ge 0 
\end{cases}
```

This will produce:

[image: piecewise equation]

Note: The easies way to get the LaTeX representation of the function is to insert it into builtin app called **Grapher**, right clicking on the function -> "Copy LaTeX Expression"

[image]